# How to change HAML to HTML css firework

Tags: html, css, haml

I found this beautiful code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/natewiley/pen/pvNjoz). however, it is written in HAML, how do I add this into my HTML code. I tried many things but failed could you please help.

Mentioned below is HAML

```
%div.wrap

  -10.times do
    %div.firework
      -40.times do
        %div.c
```

Please help me integrate this into my html page.

Comment: https://haml2erb.org/  is easy way to translate haml to html .... Are you aware that there is ruby code in it...

Comment: ruby code ohh I guess I have to give up then. Is there any reference where I can add cool firework into my html page

Comment: This code is really easy to make it pure html. function `.times` just create loops.

Comment: if you could help out how without creating canvas

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow because you're asking us to convert code from HAML into some other language. We expect you to try, many times, and then ask a question about a specific problem with that code. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good HAML -> ERB/HTML converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967262/is-there-a-good-haml-erb-html-converter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use the [Codepen compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NGTd.jpg) and use the code. But, my opinion is you can learn [HAML](http://haml.info/).

Comment: Just one question its projectile is very limited how can I change its width ?? I want it more over the screen.

Comment: That should be asked as a separate question.